# an especial usage of the construction" much of"

Tags: adverbs, intensifiers

> ...He is **much of** a gentlemen, and he has traveled enough to throw off that...

When or in which situation or condition would you rather use the bold part construction and could you please show me a synonym phrase or word for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'throw off that'? And can you provide other examples of '*much of* a man'? I ask this because in AmE we don't say 'he's much of something'. Or if we do it is so rare that I am not sure I have ever said it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In my opinion, **much of** is used when you want people to see the importance of the word following "much of". For example,

He is **much of** a traveler, than a shepherd.

The example above says that the subject is both a shepherd and a traveler. But he is more into travelling than in being a shepherd.

Answer (score 0):

In AmE and I am pretty sure BrE, native speakers don't use **much of** in the sense  you ask about: 'he is **much of** a gentleman'.

In English, the *negative* expression, as in 'he's **not much** of a gentlemen' is quite common.

She's **not much** of a lady.

Or

He's **not much** of a singer/athlete/actor/writer/teacher/example/swinger/worker.

The meaning is given in [Collns](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/not-much-of#not-much-of_1) as

> not to any appreciable degree or extent

and there are plenty of examples at that link.